# Issue In Face Recognition using Dlib, JNI in Android

Tags: java, android, face-recognition

I am using dlib library for face recognition. It's working but return multiple names(matching person). So I want to get best match according to Confidence value. But this method always return 0.0 value for all matching persons. So please help me solve this problem.

I tried this code.

```
 List<VisionDetRet> results = mFaceRec.recognize(mCroppedBitmap);
 long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

 ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
 String finalMatch="";
 float conf_val=0;
 for (VisionDetRet n : results) {
     System.out.println("confidence value = " + n.getConfidence());
     if(conf_val<n.getConfidence()) {
          conf_val=n.getConfidence();
          finalMatch=n.getLabel();
     }
 }

 if(finalMatch.length() != 0) {
     names.add(finalMatch);
 }
```

I used two class recognizer.h and jni_face_rec.cpp for getting match Confidence.

Comment: Is this related to C++?

Comment: I checked which file have code for recognition in jni_face_rec.cpp, so I mention c++, If I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: Your entire code is based on Java. That's why it's a big confusion anyone would've. Edit your question and add the relevant C++ code of your erroneous program since you've not tagged only Java but C++ too.

Comment: ok thanks sir for your valuable suggestion.